# Finally blocks run when the try block is cancelled

Tags: workflow, tfsbuild, cancellation, try-finally

In my TFS2012 build workflow, I have a Parallel activity, and inside some of the branches I have try-finally activities. If one branch fails (say, compilation with CodeAnalysis finds CodeAnalysis errors), then the other branches are cancelled. However, if a branch is inside a try block that has a `finally` block, the finally block runs, and if it takes more than 30 seconds then the cancellation fails with:

`BuildWarning: The workflow instance accepted a stop request but did not complete within 00:00:29.9922015. This may indicate an AsyncCodeActivity is active that does not support cancellation.`

I'd like to avoid such messages, so:

1. Can I somehow have a `try-finally` activity where the finally runs when an exception is raised inside the `try`, but not when the whole thing is cancelled?
2. If not, I want to add an `if` inside the `finally` block that the workflow had been cancelled, and not do long things. How can I know that the workflow has been cancelled?

**Edit:** This pattern appears even in DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml which comes with TFS2012 - CopyDirectory can take a long time, but it's inside a `TryCatch.Finally`:

```
<TryCatch DisplayName="Try Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items">
  <TryCatch.Finally>
    <Sequence DisplayName="Revert Workspace and Copy Files to Drop Location">
      <mtbwa:InvokeForReason DisplayName="Revert Workspace for Shelveset Builds" Reason="CheckInShelveset, ValidateShelveset">
        <mtbwa:RevertWorkspace DisplayName="Revert Workspace" Workspace="[Workspace]" />
      </mtbwa:InvokeForReason>
      <If  Condition="[Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropLocation)]" DisplayName="If DropLocation is Set">
        <If.Then>
          <mtbwa:CopyDirectory DisplayName="Drop Files to Drop Location" Source="[BinariesDirectory]" Destination="[DropLocation]" />
        </If.Then>
      </If>
    </Sequence>
  </TryCatch.Finally>
  <TryCatch.Try>
   (...)
  </TryCatch.Try>
</TryCatch>
```

Comment: 1. No, the finally block is designed specifically to be run either case. You can however catch specific exceptions types and handle differently in catch block.
2. You can but this is bad design choice, the goal of finally is to clean up and clear any working resources, free files etc. used in try.  From your description it sounds that there are stuff inside the finally that shouldn't be there. Can you please provide code example, its not clear to me witch branch your reffering with 30 seconds - the one calling the cancel or the one being canceled.

Comment: Thanks, added code sample. In my actual code I'm doing some cleanup, but it does take >30 sec - how should I manage that?

Comment: Im not sure if the warning message comes from exception handling in workflow or from the activity that tries to cancel the async process. If exception is thrown you can handle that specific type either ingore completly or add logic to delay and check status for a while untill stoped status comes back. Otherwise it might quite difficult to get rid of message.